# Why is my core data taking so long to save after adding a single entity?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data, nsmanagedobject

My core data code was taking too long, so i commented out most of the lines, simplifying it to this:

```
    NSString *storePath = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"CoreDataStore.sqlite"];
    NSString *backupSourceStorePath = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory]
                                       stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"CoreDataStoreBackup.sqlite"];

    NSManagedObjectContext *oldContext = [self version1ManagedObjectContext];
    TICDSSynchronizedManagedObjectContext *newContext = [self managedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest *oldFetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *oldEntryEntity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Entry"
                                                      inManagedObjectContext:oldContext];

    [oldFetchRequest setEntity:oldEntryEntity];

    int numberOfEntries = [oldContext countForFetchRequest:oldFetchRequest error:nil];

    int batchSize = 10;
    [oldFetchRequest setFetchLimit:batchSize];
    int offset = 0;

    while (numberOfEntries - offset > 0) {

        [oldFetchRequest setFetchOffset:offset];
        NSError *error;
        NSArray *entries = [oldContext executeFetchRequest:oldFetchRequest error:&error];

        int i = 0;
        for (NSManagedObject *entry in entries) {

            Entry *newEntry = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Entry"
                                                            inManagedObjectContext:newContext];
            i++;
            NSLog(@"i: %i", i);
        }

        [newContext save:&error];

        NSLog(@"Save error: %@", error);

        offset = offset + batchSize;

    }
```

If i don't have the `insertNewObjectForEntityForName` line in there, saving doesn't take long at all. But with that line, saving takes about a minute. There is nothing else in the data store before this. Any reason why this might be happening?

Comment: do you mean that the line `[newContext save:&error]` is taking about one minute?  Also, could you comment on the context of what you're doing - copying managed objects from one context to another?

Comment: Correct, that line is taking about a minute. Essentially, i'm copying them over. It's the only way to do standard migration with a large database. If you do it through the mapping, which is automated, it runs out of memory and is killed after a certain amount of time. So I have to do it manually.

Answer (score 0):

Put

```
[newContext save:&error];
```

outside for loop. It is not needed to run each time.

It'll resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with putting it outside of loop not just for execution purposes (speed) but because if something goes wrong in the loop do you want half or your data saved and then the other half not?  Most of the time the user expects all or none..otherwise you as the code her to figure out which entries saved correctly and which did not.

So 1.. for execution time
and 2. for manageability purposes